# ./build.bat: line 1: ::@echo: command not found

Tags: java

Anyone know why this error is occurring?

./build.bat: line 1: ::@echo: command not found
./build.bat: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ./build.bat: line 3:` if %errorlevel% neq 0 ('

Comment: Just a check - you *ARE* running it on Windows?…

Comment: @goose `./` is suspicious. Isn't it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch actually i missed that, so it's even *more* suspicious ;)

Comment: `./` works fine on Windows using PowerShell. Nothing suspicious about that. :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`.bat` is the conventional file extension for a windows batch file, and... not really anything else.

As the name suggests, a 'windows batch file' can only be run on the windows operating system. You're attempting to run it on an operating system that isn't Windows. That doesn't work, and cannot be made to work.

This sounds like someone wrote a java build in the form of a windows batch file. That is... epic levels of lunacy right there.

Find the person(s) responsible for it and yell at them.

For the past 15 years or so, the proper way to build java projects is to use maven or gradle. The 10 years before that, the proper answers were ant. Before that, make. 'windows batch file' never was a proper solution.